# How to deal with DAG lib in airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I've got a little question about dependency management for packages used in python operators

We are using airflow in a industralized mode to run scheduled python jobs. it works well but we are facing issues to deal with different python lib needed for each DAG.

Do you have any idea on how to let developers install their own dependencies for their jobs without being admin and being sure that these dependencies don't collide with other jobs ?

Would you recommend having a bash task that loads a virtual env at the beginning of the job ? Any official recommandation to do it ?

Thanks !
Romain.

Comment: I think your question warrants a great deal of clarification. What do you mean "in python operators"? "Operators" in Python normally refers to specific symbols like `+`, `-`, `in`, etc. and their semantics. What is "industrialized mode" for [tag:airflow]? Google doesn't turn anything up, so I suspect this is not standard terminology.

Comment: I also suspect your question is Too Broad. I don't see a specific, solvable problem here; you're asking for open ended advice or a technology recommendation. This type of question isn't usually a good fit for SO. That said, you'll find that most members of the SE community consider admin privileges a requirement for doing development work, so this requirement is unusual. For your actual problem, technologies like Docker are standard solutions to avoiding software conflicts on Linux. virtualenv can do so for non-native Python packages. Either is typically set up *per project* by the dev.

Comment: @jpmc26 it makes sense in the context of apache-airflow - which is tagged. Airflow has operators including `PythonOperator` https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.PythonOperator ,defines a step in a data pipeline. It's common to use Airflow for e.g. training machine learning models or running different python versions in different steps, so as you say venvs or containers are a good fit, or just calling external systems. Q is not too broad, the challenge is how to allow datascientists (the "devs" here) to run arbitrary python with conflicting deps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general I see two possible solutions for your problem:

1. Airflow has a [PythonVirtualEnvOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.PythonVirtualenvOperator) which allows a task to run in a virtualenv which gets created and destroyed automatically. You can pass a `python_version` and a list of requirements to the task to build the virtual env.
2. Set up a docker registry and use a [DockerOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/docker_operator.py) rather than a PythonOperator. This would allow teams to set up their own Docker images with specific requirements. This is how I think Heineken set up their airflow jobs as presented in their [Airflow Meetup](https://www.meetup.com/nl-NL/Amsterdam-Airflow-meetup/events/245382408/?eventId=245382408). I'm trying to see whether they posted their slides online but I can't seem to find them.

Comment: Awesome ! Exactly what I was looking for ;)

Comment: Looks like the DockerOperator has become a kubernetes operator, no sign of that link anymore.

Comment: No indeed, but it does still exist on master: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/docker_operator.py